# How to disable UI Components in android?

Tags: android

In my app when i am making service call i am just displaying the spinnerdialog or ProgressBarProcess but when it is displayed on the screen the Activity is able to take the events so that it is causing to force close the app(App not responding). How to solve this issue. how i am can disable the total UI components of the activity??

Comment: What do you mean by "the Activity is able to take the events"? Events of what?

Comment: Show your logcat when you are getting the force close.

Comment: Service call means what ??? are you starting a Android Service or and Network operation . If you are starting a Android Service then no need to show progress dialog for this..hope you can understand.

Comment: you have a "enabled"(dont remenber now the exact name) property, otherwise you can change the visitibility or maibe you should run your process on differents threads to avoid this

Answer (score 1):

doesn't seems any direct solution for this. but you use one trick while creating xml layout of screen

Put your entire screen in FrameLayout and and an ImageView just below your view

```
<FrameLayout>
   <YourLayout></YourLayout>
   <ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

set imageview visibility invisible and also alpha transparency 0 at first and register touch event of activity.

when you need to disable your event at that time make it visible
and in onTouch event check it's id and do nothing in that block